# Python DictWriter not writing correctly with lineterminator as '\r\n'

Tags: python, file, csv, dictionary, writer

I'm using Python 3 on Unix.

My first requirement:

- Each line break should be `'\r\n'`

Easy. I just use:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='\r\n') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, restval="-", fieldnames=headers, delimiter='|')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(rows)
```

The problem now is that in the actual content of the file, in the actual data, some of the values contain newline characters (`\n`).

Using `open(filename, 'w', newline='\r\n')` overwrites all the `'\n'` values with `'\r\n'`.

Which bring me to my second requirement:

- Any newline characters in the actual data should not be affected.

So I thought using this would fix it:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, restval="-", fieldnames=headers, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\r\n')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(rows)
```

My understanding of the above is each line break will be `\r\n` and any other `'\n'` values in the data won't be affected.

But it actually seems to have no affect on the line endings now.

Any ideas?

Comment: csv.DictWriter() defaults to '\r\n' already, adding 'lineterminator='\r\n'' is redundant https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter try setting newline='' to ensure no translation takes place with open(), from there can determine where the problem lies.